# VS Code c++ 'thread' not in namespace std

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-code

Yeah the headline pretty much sums up my problem. I can even peek into the header where thread is defined.

Building is not a problem ! atleast with this code snippet. Just the error markings are my problem !

Error: 
"no member named 'thread' in namespace 'std'"

compile task: 
"command": "g++ -Wall -g -std=c++17 -pthread main.cpp -o CANToolLinux"

clang:
clang version 4.0.1-6 (tags/RELEASE_401/final) Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu Thread model: posix

Stackoverflow want me to type some more Details but i really dont know what details are needed here. Pretty new to VS Code. Another stupid thing that has nothing to do with this problem i guess is that after some time my c_cpp_properties.json forgets all include paths i typed in. But that happend yesterday.Today the file seems fine.

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void work()
{
   //Do something
}

int main()
{
  std::thread t(work);

  t.join();

  return 0;
}
```

my c_cpp_properties.json:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "/usr/include/c++/7",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7",
                "/usr/include/c++/7/backward",
                "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include-fixed",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu",
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-37"
                ],
        "defines": [],
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "/usr/include/c++/7",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7",
                "/usr/include/c++/7/backward",
                "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include-fixed",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu",
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-37"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        },
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
    }
],
"version": 3
```

project in VS Code:
[project Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfErA.png)

Comment: You might need `-std=c++11` (or newer).

Comment: Can you show us the compiler command line please?  (And what version of clang are you using?)

Comment: BTW: Bravo on the [mcve]!

Comment: using the std::vector works ?

Comment: @MikevanDyke yes it does...

Comment: Did you check that the file "thread" really is in one of the pathes? Did you check if there are multiple "thread" files and if the right one is used? Did you check with other symbols from "thread"?

Comment: @WernerHenze like i said in my post i can even peek into the definition of "thread", so yes the file exist and is found by VS Code

Comment: When you "peek" into the definition of `thread`, what exact file does it open? Is it in one of the include path listed in your property file?

Comment: Is it possible that `thread` be defined in another namespace, like `std::experimental` or something?

Comment: It opens the thread.c from /usr/include/c++/7 and yes this is included as you can see in my c_cpp_properties.json

Comment: @YSC the file "thread" claims to use the namespace std

Comment: I'm sorry for you, I have absolutely no clue. Can you build by invoking clang directly?

Comment: @YSC yes i can. From VS Code and from commandline but these errors persist.

Comment: you said it opens thread.c? is that a typo? 'cause it should open a header file

Comment: it opens a file called "thread" with the type C source code. Should it really open a header ?

Comment: "thread" without any file extension should be fine, that's the header file. Hmm, I'm also out of ideas...

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/LanguageServer/c_cpp_properties.json.md shows "{}" around the complete file content. Your file does not seem to contain those!?

Comment: it does contain theses. just forgot to add them to this post sorry.